# json formats - which one to use?

Tags: json, sorting

What is the difference between these two JSON formats? Which format should I use?

```
[{
    "employeeid": "12345",
    "firstname": "joe",
    "lastname": "smith",
    "favoritefruit": "apple"
}, {
    "employeeid": "45678",
    "firstname": "paul",
    "lastname": "johnson",
    "favoritefruit": "orange"
}]
```

OR

```
[
    ["employeeid", "firstname", "lastname", "favoritefruit"],
    ["12345", "joe", "smith", "apple"],
    ["45678", "paul", "johnson", "orange"]
]
```

Comment: Without knowing the context, I would say the first is much more understandable, array of objects.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your response. Yes, the first one is what i am expecting. However, the second format is the one i got when using system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer. Both of them are valid, but I am just wondering if any benefits one over the other?

Comment: @AlexW. don't use the second one [JavaScriptSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says "Json.NET should be used serialization and deserialization.".

Comment: then what's wrong with Json.NET?

Comment: @AlexW. Nothing is wrong with Json.Net, the documentation says it *should* be used in place of system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.

Comment: Though I'm still not sure how you got the second result, as the example on the MSDN documentation for system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer should look more like the first one.

Comment: var csv = new List<string[]>(); // or, List<YourClass>
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt");
foreach (string line in lines)
    csv.Add(line.Split(',')); // or, populate YourClass          
string json = new 
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(csv);

Comment: the above codes produced the second format.

Answer (score 0):

Definately first one. It will create array of employee object while second one will create array of array of objects which will be more difficult to parse in most of language.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.

The first is much easer to parse if you want to create employee objects to work with.

The second may be better if you need to work on the "raw" data only. Furthermore the second is much shorter. That's not important for small or medium datasets, but could be important for example if you need to transfer  large sets of employee data.

Comment: The System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer has a Deserialize method which can take either format and convert to a list of employee objects.

Comment: If there is no difference in handling, I'd save bandwidth and take the second one.

Comment: that made wondering. maybe the first one is old, and the second one is a newer format.

Comment: No, both are ok. It's not a question of old or new. It really depends on your needs. As a rule of thumb I would transfer as less data as possible. Size doesn't really matter if you need to transfer sets of 100 employees per minute or day, but matters a lot if you need to transfer it 100+ times a second or if you have thousands of emloyees.